Add anti-RE information to the faq
I totally agree with Gilles that questions about trying to make reverse engineering harder are appropriate, but shouldn't we change our faq then? It's now:

Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange is for researchers and developers who explore the principles of a system through analysis of its structure, function, and operation.

I don't see there that we're talking about anti-RE-ing as well. Should we add something to the faq, and if so, what?

Yes, it should be explicitly mentioned in the FAQ. It could be explicitly specified either as a topic in the list of good-topics or as a separate line under the list. I would prefer it being added as a point in the list of good topics.

I added "deterring reverse engineering efforts" to the list of "questions about:"
